# Por que usar JavaScript se existem tantas outras tecnologias para gera conteúdo dinâmico?

Tags: cliente-servidor, lado-do-cliente, lado-do-servidor

Tecnologias e linguagens de programação especializadas pra Web, como PHP, tem como parte do seu conjunto de papéis, gerar conteúdo HTML dinâmico (a página será apresentada pelo navegador de acordo com várias condições). E existem várias tecnologias que deixam as páginas muito dinâmicas: O próprio PHP, Java Servlets e JSP, Perl CGI, ASP.NET, etc...

E o tal JavaScript foi feito para rodar em navegadores para gerar páginas dinâmicas.

A pergunta é:
**Se essas tecnologias que rodam do lado servidor já acrescentam tanto dinamismo as páginas, então para quê JavaScript?**

Comment: O Javascript serve para dar mais dinamismo, efeitos, controle e agilidade as páginas. Por exemplo, um site ter que ficar fazendo toda hora uma requisição de uma página completa e digamos bem pesada ao servidor, quando era necessário atualizar uma pequena div com a informação de apenas 2 campos (valor1 + valor2). 
Isso é algo extremamente custoso ao servidor. Em javascript, vc resolve isso. Existem outros casos q js ajuda com ajax

Comment: Então acho que entendi: Cada lado tem sua responsabilidade. A resposta foi satisfeita. Obrigado aos poucos que responderam e desculpem pela parcialidade que eu inclui na pergunta.

Answer (score 13):

## Diferenças

Existe uma diferença entre as linguagens, cada uma tem seu ponto de alcance e assim podem fazer coisas específicas.

Por exemplo em JavaScript por se tratar de uma linguagem Client-Side você não poderia fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados com segurança, pois o seu JavaScript é público, e todos poderiam observar suas credenciais do servidor do banco de dados. Isso é responsabilidade da linguagem Server-Side.

Já no Server-side o cliente não tem acesso ao código, tudo que está lá é sigiloso, toda sua lógica de negócios, seus acessos, credenciais, e etc. Imagina se o Google desenvolve-se todo o algorítimo e lógica de negócios em JavaScript, todos saberiam o grande segredo, certo?

Server-Side basicamente é:

- PHP, ASP.NET, etc.
- Lógica de negócios.
- Acesso ao banco de dados.
- Request e renderização.

Linguagens Server-side agem no início do Request até a renderização do HTML da página, já as linguagens Client-Side atuam após a renderização, basicamente:

- Interações com mouse, teclado.
- Animações, *drag in drop*, *sliders*.
- Requisições *ajax*.
- Validações de formulários diâmicas (você pode validar os campos sem precisar fazer um novo request).

> **Nota:** Vale lembrar que a linguagem JavaScript não é exclusiva e nem se limita apenas ao
> Client-Side, apesar da grande maioria do seu uso ser nesse intuito. Hoje em dia a mesma
> é utilizada também como linguagem Server-Side, ver o exemplo do
> [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org), e até mesmo para algumas aplicações.

Segue um ótimo [artigo](http://tableless.com.br/camadas-de-desenvolvimento-client-side/) do Diego Eis do [Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/) comentando as camadas do Client-Side para web.

Uma linguagem completa a outra *e vice-e-versa que nem feijão com arroz*.

## [Server-side](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_server-side)

> A linguagem de servidor, ou Server-side scripting, é a linguagem que
> vai rodar "por trás dos panos", fornecendo a lógica principal da
> aplicação. Funciona da seguinte maneira: sempre que o usuário faz um
> HTTP request (entra numa página, clica num link, etc), o pedido é
> enviado para o servidor. A linguagem server-side recebe o requerimento
> (Request) e faz o processamento. Depois, transforma o resultado final
> em um XHTML e envia para o navegador. É a linguagem server-side que
> vai verificar se o usuário está logado, vai buscar informações no
> banco de dados etc.
>
> Como a linguagem server-side processa as
> requisições antes de enviar para o navegador, isso significa que uma
> vez que a página foi enviada ao navegador do usuário, não há mais nada
> que a linguagem server-side possa fazer até que um novo "Request"seja
> enviado. Ou seja, não é possível usar estas linguagens para manipular
> a página do usuário em tempo real. Para o usuário, a linguagem
> server-side não importa, e ele nem tem como descobrir qual linguagem
> está sendo usada. (Wikipédia)

## [Client-side](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_client-side)

> A linguagem de cliente, ou client-side scripting, é a linguagem que é executada no lado cliente, ou seja, no computador do próprio usuário, e por isso é usada nas situações em que a linguagem server-side não tem alcance. Entre as linguagens client-side, há o JavaScript, que é a única linguagem que realmente roda no navegador do usuário. Através do JavaScript é possível manipular a página do usuário diretamente, fazendo coisas dinâmicas que vão desde mudar o valor de um campo do formulário até criar uma área redimensionável que pode ser arrastada pela página.
>
> Como todo o código JavaScript está no próprio navegador, o usuário
> pode ver o código e pode também, através da utilização de alguns
> programas, manipular o código. Isso faz com que as linguagens
> client-side sejam inseguras pra fazer coisas como acessar um banco de
> dados. Juntas, as linguagens server-side e client-side se
> complementam. (Wikipédia)

Comment: +1 pelo esforço de coletar tanta informação útil. Agora, só um detalhe: Javascript não é necessariamente uma linguagem client side. Ela foi criada para servir a esse propósito, mas hoje em dia é possível rodar Javascript do lado do servidor também (com o node.js, por exemplo).

Comment: @Renan Eu iria acrescentar essa informação, porém fiquei com receio de complicar um pouco o entendimento. Mas acho  válido, de forma a não tendenciar que o uso do JS se limita apenas ao Client-Side.

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta já responde.

Existem vários motivos, vou citar apenas o principal.

Pelo fato rodar no cliente, o javascript não necessita de acesso constante ao servidor.

Se você fizer tudo no servidor ele deverá desponder requisições de granularidade baixa (tipo requisições pra saber se o usuário informou algum campo). Agora imagina um sistema com 2 bilhões de usuários (tipo o facebook). Certamente o servidor precisaria do triplo da potência para suportar tantas requisições.

Então é interessante utilizar javascript para balancear o processamento entre o cliente e o servidor.

EDIT: Eu poderia falar sobre recursos como ajax [Cross-Domain](http://www.lucaspeperaio.com.br/blog/ajax-cross-domain-recupere-conteudos-de-outros-sites-somente-com-ajax-e-jsonp) e [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Mas vou deixar apenas algumas referências.

Comment: Poderia postar novamente? Eu havia pego o EDIT mas acho que você excluiu logo depois.

Answer (score 3):

Entendo que a pergunta não diz respeito especificamente à linguagem Javascript e sim ao conceito de executar um linguagem no cliente, especificamente num navegador web. Nesse sentido, parece que das respostas foi direto ao ponto.

Existem vários motivos pelos quais alguém quer executar uma linguagem no *client*. Alguns são legítimos, outros não.

## Usabilidade, Interatividade, Experiência do usuário

Usuário feliz continua usando o sistema e valoriza o negócio.

- Validação durante o preenchimento, com *feedback* imediato.
- Atualizações assíncronas de informações sem a ação do usuário.
- Interatividade: arrastar e soltar, pequenas animações, etc.
- Auxílio ao usuário, permitindo-o executar ações com menos esforço: campos auto-completar, menus interativos, *sliders*, etc.

Tudo isso faz muita diferença para quem acessa uma página. Um site de notícias, uma galeria de fotos, tudo isso fica muito melhor com Javascript.

Para muitos isso pode parecer algo sup,rfluo. Se você acha isso, faça argumente com os fundadores do Google, Amazon, Facebook, Microsoft, Apple, etc.

## Integração com recursos locais

Outra área não tão explorada é acesso a recursos locais, isto é, que estão na estação do usuário. Exemplos são digitalizadores, leitores de código de barras, mouse e teclado.

É claro que na maioria dos casos Javascript não é suficiente para isso, mas estou me referindo a plugins de navegadores ou componentes ActiveX, por exemplo.

## Balanceamento de carga

Mais recentemente, com a ascensão do CSS, HTML5 e navegadores mais poderosos e rápidos, começaram a surgir muitas aplicações RIA (*Rich Internet Application*), isto é, que começam a trazer boa parte do processamento antes realizado apenas no servidor novamente para o cliente.

A centralização do processamento parece oscilar ao longo dos anos. Primeiramente tudo era processado num *mainframe* e acessado via estações "burras". Então veio o *desktop* e tudo passou a ser distribuído nos clientes. Então veio a web e tomou o rumo inverso. Voltamos ao servidor "inteligente" e às estações que só exibem e enviam dados. Atualmente, estamos num ponto mais equilibrado. A maior parte das regras de negócio são executadas no servidor, mas as estações estão cada vez mais "inteligentes", no sentido de que são interativas e ricas visualmente e em funcionalidade.

Temos como bons exemplos disso tecnologias como o Google GWT ou [Cappuccino](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/).

Um projeto GWT, por exemplo, é implementado em Java e possui dois pacotes principais: *client* e *server*. A parte *client* é convertida em javascript e executa no navegador, geralmente responsável por toda a parte visual e por chamadas RPC via interfaces à parte que fica no *server*. Praticamente todos os produtos Google como Gmail, Drive e Calendar usam essa tecnologia. A resposta ao usuário é muito mais rápido e o servidor é usado para o que realmente importa.

O projeto Cappuccino é um framework que abstrai quase totalmente o desenvolvimento de um sistema web. Você desenvolve numa linguagem chamada Objective-J, que é uma mistura de Javascript com Objective-C, para gerar uma aplicação rica. O *back-end* ou *server* deve utilizar alguma linguagem para permitir comunicação e persistência de dados, mas a implementação é independente dessa camada.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que uma resposta muito completa foi formulada por um dos fundadores da rede Stack Exchange, [**Jeff Atwood**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1), no artigo [***JavaScript, a língua franca da Web***](http://blog.codinghorror.com/javascript-the-lingua-franca-of-the-web/).

Passagens selecionadas:

> [Radicalmente de código aberto, a natureza viral](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000661.html) do menu "Exibir código-fonte" é certamente uma parte essencial do sucesso da Web. Mas isso é somente uma parte da história. A maturidade crescente da implementação JavaScript nos browsers modernos é a [fundação do presente e futuro da Web](http://www.paulgraham.com/web20.html).

<sup>[...]</sup>

> Independente dos sentimentos originais contra a linguagem, o JavaScript atravessou um longo caminho desde o maus velhos tempos de 1995. Agora temos poder de CPU para queimar nas máquinas-cliente; tanto poder, de fato, que mesmo uma linguagem dinâmica e interpretada como o JavaScript pode ser um ambiente digno de confiança de desenvolvimento *client side*.

<sup>[...]</sup>

> Apesar de todos os pretendentes ao trono, JavaScript não irá embora tão cedo pois seu tempo de computação é o mais onipresente do mundo. É hora que aprendamos a aceitar e adotar o JavaScript em vez de lutar contra ele cegamente. Isso não significa que não possamos explorar alternativas -- mas a melhor maneira de transcender as limitações do JavaScript é mergulhar nessas mesmas limitações. Dessa maneira, pelo menos você sabe pelo que está lutando, e o que as alternativas realmente significam.

<sup>[...]</sup>

> **O JavaScript é a [língua franca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) da Web. O perigo de ignorá-la é totalmente seu.**

<sup>[...]</sup>

> Há excitantes alternativas ao JavaScript no horizonte. Algumas terão sucesso, outras não. Em meio a todo o tumulto sobre novas ferramentas e opções, não esqueça que o **JavaScript permanece uma excelente escolha para o desenvolvimento de *rich internet applications*** -- e, como língua franca da Web, seu sucesso é *garantido*.

---

E para quem quiser acompanhar a trajetória do Jeff e sua relação com o JavaScript, recomendo estudar seu novo empreendimento: [**Discourse**](http://www.discourse.org/), uma ferramenta para Fórums de código aberto. É praticamente o mesmo conceito técnico/sociológico por trás do Stack Overflow, mas aplicado à discussão no formato fórum.

Answer (score 0):

Todas as linguagens citadas, para se tornarem dinâmicas para o usuário fazem uso de JavaScript, do contrário, são paginas que são geradas dinamicamente, mas não possuem a tal dinamicidade aos olhos do usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Razões que eu considero as principais, em decorrência do javascript poder rodar no cliente:

- Tempo de resposta rápido, para operações de GUI
- Economizar banda tanto do usuário como do servidor

Razões para usar javascript, de forma geral:

- amplamente utilizado, portanto o suporte é garantido
- possui uma multitude de ferramentas e bibliotecas, o que permite fazer praticamente tudo o que você imaginar